# Where can you download 32 bit edition of Google Chrome for Ubuntu OS?

Tags: google-chrome, 16.04, 32-bit

Where can you download 32 bit edition of Google Chrome for Ubuntu OS?

Comment: You cannot, Google discontinued it :) That's one of the many prices that you pay if you use proprietary software. They decide to shut it down and you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: see : http://betanews.com/2015/11/30/google-killing-chrome-for-32-bit-linux/ ___ and : http://www.xda-developers.com/xda-external-link/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued/

Answer (score 9):

Google has discontinued chrome for 32 bit machines running Ubuntu. If you go to the chrome download page and hit the download button you'll see that it only offers 64-bit options.

A simple Google search will also pull up a bunch of articles about it--here's a couple I found:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued
http://betanews.com/2015/11/30/google-killing-chrome-for-32-bit-linux/

Comment: Google Chrome for 32 bit:
version 33 [link] (http://bit.ly/gcu32deb)
version 48 [link] (http://bit.ly/chrome48deb32bit)
Thank you.

Comment: Other compatibles answers on [StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267587/where-to-download-chrome-32bit-since-it-has-been-discontinued-by-google).

Answer (score 6):

Google killed the 32bit version of Chrome for Linux. The link on their site is removed. Even if you find the 32bit version this means that no update for security holes will be available.

I think you can still get Chromium in 32bit version.

To install chromium, open terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```