# Is chromium-browser from Trusty repos up-to-date security-wise?

Tags: 14.04, updates, chromium

Ubuntu Trusty reaches EOL only in April 2019. But `chromium-browser` package is several releases out-of-date, at least if we judge by version number. Namely, current version in Bionic is [`69.0.3497.81-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/chromium-browser), while in Trusty it's [`65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/chromium-browser).

This makes me wonder whether it can be considered secure.

I don't know of any security bugs fixed between these versions, but if there are any, does the version in Ubuntu Trusty have the patches backported? Or is it effectively abandoned for the remaining half a year of LTS life?

**NOTE**: unlike [the other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/888443/113421) proposed as duplicate target for this one, this question doesn't ask *why*, it asks whether outdated-version Chromium is still up-to-date security-wise.

Comment: What does `apt policy chromium-browser` show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't Chromium up-to-date in all the Ubuntu LTS repos, like Firefox is?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888443/why-isnt-chromium-up-to-date-in-all-the-ubuntu-lts-repos-like-firefox-is)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex no it isn't, see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version numbers can be misleading.

The Ubuntu Security Team patches vulnerabilities in 65.0 (usually using an upstream-provided patch), then pushes the update to you via Ubuntu's -security repository. The patched version is still 65.0, since it's not a new upstream release. Since it's no longer stock 65.0, a supplemental version number is added at the end (that's the '0Ubuntu1' at the end of the version string).

The Security Team won't push a new (untested) upstream version 69.0 to merely address a patchable vulnerability. Pushing a new upstream version outside the normal release cycle is precisely the opposite of the software stability that an LTS release is intended to provide.

The [Ubuntu Security Team](https://usn.ubuntu.com/) maintains a searchable database of all known vulnerabilities in all Ubuntu packages, so you can see the status for yourself without guessing.

Comment: Hmm, I get `security.ubuntu.com refused to connect` for your link. Could you check that you can access it?

Comment: This is somewhat of a dangerous position on browser security, since it relies on known vulnerabilities, which will naturally focus on the official stable and newer versions of the browser, both for focusing on the future and for the common misconception that everyone is automatically updating to the latest stable version if they care about security (thus old versions can be ignored). If code with an unseen vulnerability is replaced in a newer version, it's unlikely many workers on the project will be going over the thrown-out or modified-away code for security vulnerabilities, adding risk.